# Unable to create new project

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I'm trying to create my first android app with Titanium Studio 3.1 on Windows 7. I've unzipped the android sdk files to a folder on my hard drive and configured Titanium Studio to look at this folder. If I look under "Configure Native SDKs" and click on Android SDK, it says everything is installed correctly. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The error occurs after I click "Finish" when i'm setting up a New Mobile Project. The error also says "Run titanium help for available commands." and "Resource '.../app.js' does not exist.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think the generation of the project files are dependent on this, but make sure you have Java SDK 1.6 32-bit installed.  It might be on 1.7, check the documentation.  For Windows this appears to be a common issue that some had a 64-bit version installed.

Comment: I've double checked that I am using a 32-bit version of Java SDK 1.6. I have also tried installing 1.7 32-bit. I am still getting the error. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Have you set your environment variables correctly? Try the following commands in command prompt: java, javac, adb. If any one of it give error your settings are wrong

Comment: I double checked the environment variables and I believe this is where my issue was. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with environment variables. Needed to change the PATH environment variables to the correct locations.

Comment: What variables did you set. GA 3.2.1 (MacOS)

Comment: I don't have the exact variables I set anymore, but this link might help you: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Software_Locations_and_Environment_Variables-section-29004844_SoftwareLocationsandEnvironmentVariables-Windows

Comment: One Variable which we found while making Titanium Eclipse editor to work properly in Windows XP is

LOCALAPPDATA. This variable is not defined in Windows XP, hence set this as any normal variable pointing to some directory